# Pass route data from View to controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Guys ! I am new to Asp.net MVC 5, and I want to create a website with announcements. I pass a list with announcements to View, and o display them with a @foreach. 
Now, in  I put a "Show details" to show more details of that announcement. How will I do that?

```
    @foreach (var a in @ViewBag.Ann)
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>@a.Title</h2>
        <h3>@a.CategoryName</h3>
        <p hidden>@a.Id</p>
        <a href="#">Show Details</a>

    </div>

}
```

How can I create a link with the announcement Id from this?

Comment: Use ajax to make a call to a controller that returns a partial view of the additional details and add it to the DOM

Comment: Ok, but how I will take the exact Id from the announcement where I press "Show Details" ?

Comment: Add it as a `data-` attribute in the link and extract it in your `.click()` handler (there is no need for your `<p hidden>@a.Id</p>` element)

Comment: Can you show me an example, please?

Comment: `<a href="#" class="showdetails" data-id="@a.Id">Show Details</a>` and `$('.showdetails').click(function({ $.get(yourUrl, { id: $(this).data('id') }, function(data) { // update DOM }); });` (you need to at least make some effort yourself)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach (var a in @ViewBag.Ann)
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2 >@a.Title</h2>
        <h3>@a.CategoryName</h3>

        <a href="ShowDetails/@a.Id">Show Details</a>

    </div>

}
```

This work now..Thank you, guys !

Comment: If you want to redirect, why not just `@Html.ActionLink("ShowDetails", "ShowDetails", new { id = a.Id })`